# Words For Frequencies Less Than An Hour

Tags: time

I'm writing a scheduling program and need to show frequency options ranging from once a minute to once a year. Anything over an hour is pretty simple, but I'm looking a formal term for frequencies under an hour.

```
Every...   | Term
Year       | Annual
6 Months   | Semi Annual
3 Months   | Quarterly
1 Month    | Monthly
Week       | Weekly
Day        | Daily
Hour       | Hourly
30 Minutes | Semi Hourly (?)
15 Minutes | Quarter Hourly (?)
10 Minutes | Decminutely (?)
5 Minutes  | Pentminutely (?)
2 Minutes  | Biminutely (?)
Minute     | Minutely (?)
```

*If anyone has an idea for a better SE forum that this should be posted on please let me know*

Comment: Sorry, but I've never heard anything other than either "N times an hour" or "every N minutes".  I suspect that if you try to invent a term you will just cause confusion.

Comment: [Why not invent your own terms?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caedite_eos._Novit_enim_Dominus_qui_sunt_eius)

Comment: Note that in your title, "frequencies less than an hour" is ambiguous.  Do you mean "less frequent than once an hour" (the physicist's interpretation)? Or do you mean "recurring with a period shorter than an hour" (the colloquial interpretation)? It's clear from the question text that you mean the latter, in which case "frequencies _shorter_ than an hour" would have been clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are the expressions *[half-hourly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/half-hourly) and [quarter-hourly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quarter-hourly)*, but *every 30/15/10/5/2 minutes* is clearer and avoids misunderstandings.

Answer (score 8):

I would definitely recommend sending this to the [User Experience SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com).

For clarity, I would consistently use the "every *n* *units*" format: "every year", "every 6 months", "every quarter", *etc.*

Comment: For times of one hour and above there is absolutely nothing wrong with *hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, annually* etc. But for times of less than an hour I would always say *every n minutes*.

Comment: @WS2 Sure. I have had instances where I had to provide intervals that felt a little awkward as adverbs: semi-monthly, semi-annually, biennially, quinquennially. It can be a lot easier to program something like that if the format is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I am so late! I just had the same problem as a translator. I guess the best solution is:

(my case) vitals monitored regularly, more frequently than once an hour 
or
vitals monitored regularly, less frequently than once an hour.

:)